# SEAL-CKKS max multiplication depth

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am trying to understand how SEAL-CKKS scheme works and I wonder what multiplication level can we achieve using this scheme?

Like 100 possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will most likely scale out of bounds with 100 multiplications.
Even with quite large polynomial modulus degree with small scale goes out of bounds with tens of multiplications.